# Is there a Storybook.js for .net razor?

Tags: .net, razor, frontend

In particular I'm using asp.net awesome controls, but if telerik controls work with a 'component explorer' than that setup might be good for me too.

Comment: I haven't found one yet but was going to start working on one if anyone is interested

Comment: @RickyHartmann   How are you planning to get started?  Any way to use the code base https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook ?